# Business Intelligence Development Studio Unable to connect to database

Tags: ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, reporting-services

I am trying to create a SSRS report using  Business Intelligence Development Studio 2008;

I want to connect to CRM online,so that I can create reports.I am using `Data Source= LINE500\sage;Initial Catalog=cs3live; Integrated Security=false; User Id=normuser;Password=password` as connection string. But its unable to connect,showing connection string is not valid. Where can I get the valid connection string?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to connect to CRM Online you need to install `Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Report Authoring Extension`, you can download from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27823

There is also the CRM 2013 version, you can download from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40343

After you need to set the type of Data Source to `Microsoft Dynamics CRM Fetch`

To build your connection string follow this article:

http://garethtuckercrm.com/2011/03/24/fetch-xml-reports-for-crm-2011-online/